# JSLink OnPreRender

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, client-side-rendering

I am facing a problem while using `OnPreRender` and Item events.

According to my requirement I have to read a specific permission from a list.

I use `OnPreRender` even to do that, once I do that I have to apply the filter on rows. While I read my permissions the item render event is already passed.

What could be the way to go about it?

Answer (score 0):

In `PreRender` event you should set flag, if and when you are actually rendering the control you should check for the flag and based on that you can set the logic for filtration. Otherwise you can make REST query to get the permission before rendering the control and then you can determine.

Comment: In fact what is happening that even I use the Rest call which is async. The browser request is single threaded and the success or failure method of my rest call is invoked once all the rows are already rendered. So its already over.

Comment: You can make the Ajax call sync. And with that you should call REST.